# SWRevealViewController, sliding out from on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

is it possible to get the SWRevealViewController to slide out on top of the front view controller instead of under it? Been trying to look for a solution for this but not found anything. Modified the shadow at first but still doesn't look right. Need the top controller to remain static with the reveal one sliding on top. Would really appreciate any tips. thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?